# User input within functions, can I make it 'global'?

Tags: function, python-3.x, user-input

The best way I can phrase this question = *'Can I use a 'programmer' defined function to grab user input, and then use that input within another user defined function?'*

Background info:

```
    1. Python 3.x please
    2. I understand function statements are usually local, not global, but I am unsure if that is 100% the case
    3. I usually grab user input during the main function, and then call a function to act on that input, so even though it is 'local' the called function is using that data
```

- I want to know if there is a way to create a function that will be able to grab user input, and then use the information gathered within that function within any other user defined function.

I would like to create a function that will gather user input, instead of grabbing in the main function using statements, if possible. So that way I can grab a list from the user using that function, instead of using my global statement of L

Here is my current example:

```
#Creating global list to be called on by the functions
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #total is 45


# Sum a list using 'For Loop'
def sumF(n):
    total = 0
    for i in L:
        total += i
    return total

# Sum a list using 'While Loop'
def sumW(x):
    count = 0
    total = 0
    while count < len(L):
        total += L[count]
        count += 1 
    return total

# Sum a list using Recursion
def sumR(g,h):
    if h == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return g[h-1] + sumR(g,h-1)

def combine(a,b):
    L3 = []
    a = a.split()
    b = b.split()
    # Currently only works when lists have same length?
    for i in range(len(a)):
        L3.append(a[i])
        L3.append(b[i])
    print('The combination of the lists = %s' %L3)


#main funtion to call all the other functions
def main():
    print('The number %d was calculated using the for-loop function.' %(sumF(L)))
    print('The number %d was calculated using the while-loop function.' %(sumW(L)))
    print('The number %d was calculated using a recursive function.' %(sumR(L,len(L))))
    user = input('Enter a list of elements, with each being seperated by one space: ')
    user2 = input('Enter a second list of elements, with each being seperated by one space: ')
    combine(user,user2)

#selection control statement to initiate the main function before all others
main()
```

Comment: hi you can set up a global object to read input. if you are reading list then declare object as `my_input_list = []` . Inside your read function you can assign values to globally declared object. Or your function can return values to caller as like input() which you assigned to user1 and user2

Comment: Where is `n` used in the definition of `sumF(n)` ?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Ah, my mistake. I should have the loop iterate over n, which would still be L, but nice catch.

Comment: @NishanthShetty Haha, any other day and I would have been able to remember that :/ Thanks for helping me see it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the variable `global` inside the function

```
>>> def func(max_input):
        global list1
        list1=[]
        for i in range(max_input):
            list1.append(input('enter item and press enter'))
        return list1     #Optional
```

**Output**

```
>>> 
>>> func(5)
enter list item and enter1
enter list item and enter2
enter list item and enter3
enter list item and enter4
enter list item and enter5

>>> list1
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>>
```

If you are refering the variable from function which is inside another function then refer it as 
`nonlocal`

```
>>>def func2():
       var1=[] #local to func2
       def func3():
           nonlocal var1 #refers to var1 in func2 function
```